# Webgl: max vertex uniform vectors in ANGLE-based implementations

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webgl

I have some rendering code which queries `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS`, reports this value to console and computes uniform array sizes based on it. The goal is to use (almost) all available GPRs for some batched rendering.

The code runs on desktop (Linux and Windows) and in browsers when built with emscripten. I tried to run it on Nvidia, AMD and Intel HD GPUs with all combinations of GPUs and OS.

On Linux both native and web versions work fine and report `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` = 1024 on my GPUs.

Then I reboot to Windows, where native version works fine too, while web version in both Chrome and Firefox report `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` = 4096 and work fine with Nvidia and AMD. Looks like it uses phantom uniforms which were unavailable for native build. So my first question: how? Does it swap extra values from memory?

Then I run this code on Intel HD 4000 GPU on Windows. Native version works as expected (with correct value of `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS`), but web version reports 4096 `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` and corrupts some of the uniforms: geometry gets glitched when uniform array is used in vertex shader.

Why does ANGLE report wrong `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS`? Is it a bug? How can I get correct value or otherwise use all available uniforms? No UBOs please, I'm bound with webgl1.

Quick reproduction for webgl: https://sergeyext.github.io/sergeyext/max_vertex_uniform_vectors/start_webgl.html

Comment: The first thing to check is what does WebGL report to see if the bug is in emscripten or WebGL: https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/r4qha5fk/

Comment: @gman Surely I tried a report from pure JS. Same result (4096). I asked ANGLE developers and they say it's OK. It's always 4096 on ANGLE, as uniforms are implemented as UBOs: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angleproject/QVJBzdJey4s

Comment: I had a similar issue on linux with the Intel HD 4000 reporting false values not only for uniform vectors but also for varyings, I wrote it off as a driver issue.